# "find" expression to find all directories within the current directory which contain dockerfiles?

Tags: bash, directory, find

I'm trying to write a `find` expression which finds all directories within the current directory which contain a docker file.

So the following things would match with result:

`./dir1/Dockerfile` -> `./dir1`
`./test/Dockerfile` -> `./test`

Would not match:

`./dir2/dir3/Dockerfile`

The `find` statement must exclude the current directory as a result along with any hidden directories.

So far I've tried the following statements:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -regextype egrep -type d -a \( -not -regex '.+\(git|dir\)$' \)
```

But I haven't been able to get them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Search for `Dockerfile` and use `cut` to extract the Dockerfile from the paths found:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name Dockerfile  | cut -f1,2 -d/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without `find`, just shell globbing:

```
for f in ./*/Dockerfile; do printf '%s\n' "${f%/*}"; done
```

`./*/Dockerfile` matches files names `Dockerfile` that are in a subdirectory; the parameter expansion `${f%/*}` removes the last slash and what follows it.

`*` doesn't match hidden directories, and a Dockerfile in the current directory would be excluded as well.

For the case where nothing matches, you might want to enable the `shopt -s nullglob` option so `./*/Dockerfile` expands to the empty string if there is no match.